# Concat foreign key values from a self related table

Tags: mysql

I have a products database which has a multi-tier category structure. Products are assigned to a category. The category table looks like this:

```
id     name            parent_id
================================
1      Electronics     NULL
2      AV              1
3      Speakers        2
4      Wireless        3
```

What I want to do is, as part of my SELECT statement for products, output a concatenated string of the category tree.

The product is always assigned to the last category, so for example, Product "500w Wireless Speakers" would be assigned to `category_id` 4 (based on the above).

The ouputted column should be `Electronics-AV-Speakers-Wireless`.

Is this possible to do? I have looked at `GROUP_CONCAT()` but I'm having trouble working out the correct syntax.

Comment: As far as I know MySQL doesn't support mulit level hierarchy. At least there is no clean way.

Comment: The only solutions are to either write a stored procedure or write code in your system calling this database to loop over the results and build your tree.  There's no way to do this for any variable depth tree in simple SQL. It requires procedural code.

Answer (score 0):

Join as many times as you need, and concat the names:

```
select concat(a.name, '-', b.name, '-', c.name, '-', d.name) name
from mytable a
join mytable b on a.id = b.parent_id
join mytable c on b.id = c.parent_id
join mytable d on c.id = d.parent_id;
```